# How to uninstall, remove, or disable powerline for tmux?

Tags: tmux

Running Ubuntu 18. I configured tmux with powerlines and would like to reset back to the default look. I have tried removing all the things I remember related to powerline, the pip install, plugin from vim, purge and reinstalled tmux, deleted ~/.tmux.conf; but it sill looks likes this:

[image]

Any suggestion of what I can try? look for?

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to kill all active sessions.